# $M_{i+1} = M_i - \frac{M_i a_i a_i^T M_i}{a_i^T M_i a_i}$ and $M_1 = I$, find $M_i$ in terms of $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_i)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, induction, matrix-equations, recursion

Given a sequence of vectors $(a_1, a_2, ...)$ with $(\forall i \in \{ 1, 2, ... \} ) a_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we define the following sequence of matrices $(M_1, M_2, ...)$ with $(\forall i \in \{ 1, 2, ... \} ) M_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$:

$$ \begin{aligned}
M_1 &= I \\
M_{i+1} &= M_i - \frac{M_i a_i a_i^T M_i}{a_i^T M_i a_i} \\
\end{aligned} $$

Looking at the first few elements, we have:

$$ \begin{aligned}
M_1 &= I \\
M_{2} &= I - \frac{a_1 a_1^T}{a_1^T a_1} \\
M_{3} &= I - \frac{(a_1^T a_1) a_2 a_2^T - (a_1^T a_2) a_2 a_1^T - (a_1^T a_2) a_1 a_2^T + (a_2^T a_2) a_1 a_1^T}{(a_1^T a_1)(a_2^T a_2) - (a_1^T a_2)(a_2^T a_1)} \\
\end{aligned} $$

The problem is to find a closed form solution for $M_i$ in terms of $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_i)$.

Note that it easy to prove by induction that $(\forall i \in \{ 1, 2, ... \} ) M_i^T=M_i$ and $M_i M_i = M_i$.

I've made the following conjecture about the solution to the problem:

$$
M_{i} = I - \frac{ \sum_{ \sigma \in S_{i-1} }{ \left[ \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma) \prod_{l=1}^{i-1}{ \left[ a_l^T a_{\sigma (l)} \right ] } \sum_{k=1}^{i-1}{ \left[ \frac{a_k a_{\sigma (k)}^T}{a_k^T a_{\sigma (k)}} \right] } \right] } }{ \sum_{ \sigma \in S_{i-1} }{ \left[ \operatorname{sgn} (\sigma) \prod_{l=1}^{i-1}{ \left[ a_l^T a_{\sigma (l)} \right ] } \right] } }
$$

If my conjecture is true then it should be possible to prove it by induction, but I'm having a hard time with the algebra.

(EDIT: I'm taking a break from this problem for now, but as a note-to-self for if/when I return to it, a useful approach might be to try to isolate the $S_{i-1}$ terms from $M_{i+1}$, use this to find a simplified expression for $M_i - M_{i+1}$, and compare this expression to $\frac{M_i a_i a_i^T M_i}{a_i^T M_i a_i}$ to see if they're provably equivalent).

For context, this is part of a broader problem which is to find a closed form solution for the volume of a parallelotope defined by the vectors $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_m)$ using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation, which in turn is to be used to derive the Leibniz formula for the determinant of a matrix. Hence, I am looking for solutions to this problem which avoid relying on definitions or properties of determinants, as this would lead to circular reasoning in the broader problem.

Comment: @WillJagy I think that's right? $M_2 M_2 = \left( I - \frac{a_1 a_1^T}{a_1^T a_1} \right) \left( I - \frac{a_1 a_1^T}{a_1^T a_1} \right)
= \left( I - \frac{a_1 a_1^T}{a_1^T a_1} - \frac{a_1 a_1^T}{a_1^T a_1} + \frac{a_1 (a_1^T a_1) a_1^T}{(a_1^T a_1)(a_1^T a_1)} \right)
= \left( I - \frac{a_1 a_1^T}{a_1^T a_1} - \frac{a_1 a_1^T}{a_1^T a_1} + \frac{a_1 a_1^T}{a_1^T a_1} \right)
= \left( I - \frac{a_1 a_1^T}{a_1^T a_1} \right)
= M_2$

Comment: I see what I did..

Comment: Don't know if this will prove fruitful, but your iteration bears a striking resemblance to the Sherman-Morrison formula
$$\left(M^{-1}+aa^T\right)^{-1} = M - \frac{Maa^TM}{1+a^TMa}$$

Comment: @lynn that's really interesting, thank you, and the resemblance is indeed very striking!

Answer (score 1):

In your posting, note that $M_2$ is orthogonal projection onto $(a_1/|a_1|)^\perp$

**(A)** We want to show that **$M_{i+1}$ is orthogonal projection** onto orthogonal compliment of subspace generated by $a_k, \ 1\leq k\leq i$ by induction.

So we assume that $M_i$ satisfies the assumption.

(1) Hence easily we can showw that $M_{i+1}a_k=0$ for $1\leq k\leq i$.

(2) If $v\cdot a_k=0$ for $1\leq k\leq i$, then $M_{i+1}v=v$ :

First note that $ M_iv=v$. And since $M_ia_i$ is a linear combination of $a_k,\ 1\leq k\leq i$, then $$(M_ia_i)\cdot v=0,$$ which implies $M_{i+1}v=v$. Hence we completes the proof.

**(B)** Now **we will construct** $M_{k+1}$ : Define $A = [a_1\cdots a_k]$. By
construction of all $M_i$ we note that $A$ has rank $k$.

If $\pi$ is orthogonal projection onto column space of $A$, then
for any $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there is unique $x$ s.t. $\pi v=Ax$.

Hence $$A^TA x = A^T \pi v = A^Tv $$
so that $$ x = (A^TA)^{-1} A^T v $$
which implies that $$ \pi v =Ax = A(A^TA)^{-1} A^T v $$
Hence $$ M_{k+1} = I- \pi = I- A(A^TA)^{-1} A^T $$

Comment: OP is asking for an explicit formula. It's not clear what your answer achieves in that regard.